# Compute Singularity from the given weighted dual graph

Tags: algebraic-geometry, singularity-theory, dynkin-diagrams

For a rational surface singularity, Artin's result guarantees the existence of the fundamental cycle Z. Thinking in the reverse direction, I have the following question(s):

Que-1: Given a weighted graph, does there exist (and can we algorithmically find) a rational surface singularity, corresponding to this graph?

(
I found one result in this direction, by Stephen S T Yau (Trans. of AMS, 1979)(Title: NORMAL TWO-DIMENSIONAL ELLIPTIC SINGULARITIES). But this doesnt give much about this problem.
)

In general, given a weighted graph, we can compute the determinant of the intersection matrix, which equals the order of the divisor class group. But unless we know what are the *valid* coefficients for these $C_i$'s (so as to make it a valid fundamental cycle $Z$), we can't compute $Z\cdot Z$ and will not be able to check the rationality condition $-Z^2+Z\cdot K > 0$, where $K$ is the canonical divisor.

So if I start with random (integer) values for the coefficients in the fundamental cycle, how am I sure that the graph corresponds to the rational singularity. (In other words, I can compute $-Z^2$. But unless I know $K$, how can I compute $Z\cdot K$?) Thus the question boils down to whether I can compute **valid** $K$ from the given data?

Second question:
Suppose, I know by some theory / other information, that the graph corresponds to the rational surface singularity. Is there any way to "compute" the definining equiations of the singularity?

--Mike